# Constructor chain creates object, but is null in caller

Tags: c#

Here's what I have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IMainUIHandler MainUIHandler;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            IMainUIHandler UIHandlerMain = new MainUIHandler();
            UIHandlerMain.PlayerMgtHandler.AddNewPlayer("2020", "_", 1, 3);
   ... more stuff
       }
    }

class MainUIHandler : IMainUIHandler
    {
        public IPlayerMgtUIHandler PlayerMgtHandler { get; }
        public MainUIHandler()
        {
            PlayerMgtHandler = new PlayerMgtUIHandler();
        }
    }

 class PlayerMgtUIHandler  : IPlayerMgtUIHandler 
    {
        public List<IPlayer> NewPlayers { get; } //TODO change List to HashSet

        public void AddNewPlayer(string idPrefix, string idSeparator, int idSeqNumber,int idNumDigits)
        {
            IPlayer player=new Player(idPrefix,idSeparator,idSeqNumber,idNumDigits);
            NewPlayers.Add(player);
        }

        public PlayerMgtUIHandler()
        {
            List<IPlayer> NewPlayers = new List<IPlayer>();
        }

    }
```

Stepping through beginning at `MainWindow` from `IMainUIHandler UIHandlerMain = new MainUIHandler();`, when I get to:

```
   public PlayerMgtUIHandler()
            {
                List<IPlayer> NewPlayers = new List<IPlayer>();

        }
```

the `List<IPlayer> NewPlayers` is not nothing; it has zero elements. When I step out back to the caller PlayerMgtHandler.NewPlayers is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `List<IPlayer> NewPlayers = new List<IPlayer>();` is a local variable that only exists in the constructor. It is not the class member of the same name

Comment: You commented out InitializeComponents. Do not do that. The designer written code is executed with that and commenting it out would kill your entire User Interface. | Otherwise, UnholySheep is perfectly correct.

Comment: I think I see why you added a new list. Because you forgot to give `NewPlayers` a private set. So there is no way to set it, not even in class code.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. My intention is to be initializing the class member, not a local variable. When I hover over the class member when the `PlayerMgtUIHandler()` `new`s up `NewPlayers` it also shows count=0. So if on exit of the class the property is null how do I do it?

Comment: @Christopher ok... so since I am using an Interface that has a getter only for the List<> are you saying I can still add a private setter? Apparently so. I just did that and the compiler didn't complain

Comment: @SmileyFtW: You have to add a setter. Interfaces can only carry public Methods and Property Acessor, so there is no way for it to carry a private setter. So it missing there does not say anything, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `class PlayerMgtUIHandler` to:

```
   class PlayerMgtUIHandler  : IPlayerMgtUIHandler 
    {
        public List<IPlayer> NewPlayers { get; protected set; } //TODO change List to HashSet



        public void AddNewPlayer(string idPrefix, string idSeparator, int idSeqNumber,int idNumDigits)
        {
            IPlayer player=new Player(idPrefix,idSeparator,idSeqNumber,idNumDigits);
            NewPlayers.Add(player);
        }

        public PlayerMgtUIHandler()
        {
            NewPlayers = new List<IPlayer>();
        }

    }
```

Now it works as I wanted. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.